# React JS: setState is not defined when extending React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am refactoring some React JS components as ES6 style classes, from a previous implementation that utilized React.createClass.
In the old implementation, this.setState worked as expected.

However it looks like the setState method is not available at all when extending React.Component, even though it is documented as part of the API: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Is there some other other mechanism of updating the component state, or is this more likely an issue with my implementation.

```
function getState() {
  return {test: TestStore.getTest()}
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = getState();
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
   }
   componentDidMount() {
     TestStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
   }
   _onChange() {
     this.setState(getState());
   }
    render(){
        return <div>{this.state.test}</div>
    }
}
```

I am using react js version 0.14.7

**Edit**: The above snipped is in fact correct. The issue was due to a domain specific bug on my side

Comment: Are you defining state in the constructor or as a class attribute?

Comment: please post the relevant code part

Comment: I call this.setState in a callback envoked when something in the Flux store changes. I already tried binding the this, does not seem to make a difference

Comment: @kpimov I define state in the constructor

Comment: it is most likely a context issue. as i said, please post the relevant code part. hard to help without knowing your code.

Comment: I obviously can't copy-paste the relevant code, but I included a code snippet that I think shows what I am truing to do in a nutshell.

Comment: getState() already returns an object ... I don't think this is the issue

Comment: @BojanaPopovska your code looks good, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/293/) example. I was wrong

Comment: *"However it looks like the setState method is not available at all when extending React.Component,"* it is available. The code you posted doesn't have the issue you are talking about.

Comment: @FelixKling looks like you are right. The snipped I posted works fine, the issue I experienced was connected to a specific bug on my side, not the binding mechanism itself.